# Perl file handle Zero Instead of Variable

Tags: perl

I'm debugging someone else's Perl script and found a section that writes to a file in a manner similar to this:

```
open(0,">/file.txt");
print 0 "Hello world.";
close(0);
```

I don't understand why they've used `0` instead of a variable for the file handle name. Is there any advantage to doing it this way?

Comment: Also, see "[How does open 0; print <0>; turn every Perl program into a quine?](http://www.nu42.com/2014/10/how-does-open-0-print-turn-every-perl.html)" Just `open 0` would have opened `$0` for reading. There is no reason to use this kind of thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument of a `open` can be a variety of things:

- A bare word: `open(FH, ...)`
- A variable name: `open("FH", ...)`
- A glob: `open(*FH, ...)`
- A reference to a glob: `open(\*FH, ...)`
- A reference to an IO: `open(*FH{IO}, ...)`
- An undefined value: `open(my $fh, ...)`

Numbers will be stringified and treated as variable names. Even names not normally allowed by Perl can be used (such `123.456`).

You really should avoid such weird file handle names. In fact, you should use scalars variables for file handles, and preferably lexically-scoped ones.

```
open(my $fh, ...);
print $fh ...;
```

Comment: Please enlighten me, but is `0` not a variable but a constant?

Comment: Turns out you can even create variables with names that wouldn't normally be allowed by Perl, e.g. `open("!!!!!", ...)`.

Comment: Wow, that's a special kind of nasty.